# CakePhp Where does not take action in deeply nested associations

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I can not use `where` in deeply nested associations.

I have tried in many ways, but in every case where I use `where` it doesn't take action

Actually, my case is like in Documentation 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith

What I have tried until now

```
$query = $itemTable
      ->find('all')
      ->contain(
        [
          'Products',
          'ItemGroups',
          'ItemGroups.FeaturesItemGroups.Features',
          'Products.ProductCategories.ProductFractions',
          'Products.ProductVessels',
          'ItemCancellationReasons',
          'Features',
          'Users',
          'Users.Groups',
          'Orders',
          'ItemPrices.ItemPricesBillingDocuments.RecyclerPrices.ProductFractions' => [
            'conditions' => [
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.id IS NOT NULL',
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.billing_document_id' => $billingDocumentToRevert->id,
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.billing_document_type_id' => BillingDocumentTypes::CREDIT_INDEX,
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.active' => 1
            ]
          ]
        ]
      );
```

Second example

```
->innerJoinWith(
        'ItemPrices.ItemPricesBillingDocuments',
        function ($q) use ($billingDocumentToRevert) {
          return $q->where(
            [
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.id IS NOT NULL',
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.billing_document_id' => $billingDocumentToRevert->id,
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.billing_document_type_id' => BillingDocumentTypes::CREDIT_INDEX,
              'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.active' => 1
            ]
          )
            ->contain(['RecyclerPrices.ProductFractions']);
        }
      )
```

3.

```
$query->where([
      'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.id IS NOT NULL',
      'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.billing_document_id' => $billingDocumentToRevert->id,
      'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.billing_document_type_id' => BillingDocumentTypes::CREDIT_INDEX,
      'ItemPricesBillingDocuments.active !=' => false
    ]);
```

And as result in my debugging I am getting results where `active` flag is `false`.

Each relation from Items table is `1:many`
ItemsPrices.ItemPricesBillingDocuments is also `1:many`

Comment: With 1:many relations, I'm pretty sure that what you want to use is `matching`, not `innerJoin`. It's the next section up in the documentation you referenced.

Comment: Actually I (do not) need matching because than my object structure is not correct. With _matchingData results are always at the end of object plus each nested table is also at the same level as first one.